# How to perform an action when anybody sends a message with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm wanting to edit someone's username whenever they send a message to adding one to show how many messages they've sent, how would I do this in discord.py?

I'm setting up a bot to +1 to a number by editing their username every time they send a message.

```
    keyword = "thing"
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
          message_text = message.content.strip().upper()
          if keyword in message_text:
          await ctx.send('. . .')
```

I've tried this to just output text if it detects a keyword.

I am expecting to get an output of . . . but nothing happens, no error message, nothing, just doesn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`message_text` is all uppercase characters, but `"thing"` is lowercase

```
keyword = "thing"
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      message_text = message.content.strip().lower()
      if keyword in message_text:
          await message.channel.send('. . .')
```

Note that you can't do `ctx.send` because you're not in a command, and therefore don't have access to an invocation context object.

Comment: Thank you so much! is there a way to make it do that whenever a message is sent, regardless of keywords?

Comment: Sure, just remove the check. `on_message` is called for every message sent that the bot can "see".  Be careful, because that also includes the bots own messages, so you might want a `if message.author == bot.user: return` check